# Moving a channel to a category discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having some trouble moving a channel in discord.py. It has something to do with the position of the channel in the category. I believe that I am having some trouble with pinning the message as well, but I have not gotten any errors from that.

Current code:

```
@bot.command()
async def claim(ctx, *, message):
    channel = ctx.channel
    chanid = channel.id
    user = ctx.message.author
    userid = user.id

    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="help channels") 
    balloon = await bot.fetch_channel(841448863813861386)
    dyno = await bot.fetch_channel(841449376220053516)
    fish = await bot.fetch_channel(841449479860912209)
    post = await bot.fetch_channel(841449479860912209)

    if channel == balloon or dyno or fish:
        await ctx.message.pin(ctx.message)
        await ctx.channel.move(beginning, category=category)

        embedVar = discord.Embed(color=0x04d277)
        embedVar.set_thumbnail(url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-discord/branding/main/icons/checkmark/green-question-mark-dist.png')
        embedVar.add_field(name='Help channel opened.', value=f'You have claimed <#{chanid}>.', inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name='Asking your question:', value='Ask your question below, and staff will try to answer as best they can. Once done, use ?close to close the channel.', inline=False)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

        embedVar = discord.Embed(color=0x9be441)
        embedVar.add_field(name='Help channel opened.', value=f'<@{user.id}> has opened <#{chanid}>.', inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name='Question:', value=message, inline=False)
        return await post.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: can you add what error or trouble you are facing so that i can  be answered

Comment: sorry, here is the error: `"beginning" is not defined`

Comment: Because beginning isn't defined? You haven't defined it at all in your code. You're using it as if it is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can move it by editing channel.

```
await channel.edit(category=category_channel)
```

But your problem isn't about this. What is the `beginning` in your code?